# Append to an attribute in Enlive

Tags: clojure, enlive

Is it possible to append a value to an attribute using enlive?

example: I have this

```
<a href="/item/edit/">edit</a>
```

and would like this

```
<a href="/item/edit/123">edit</a>
```

I am currently doing this:

```
(html/defsnippet foo "views/foo.html" [:#main]
  [ctxt]
  [:a] (html/set-attr :href (str "/item/edit/" (ctxt :id))))
```

But I would prefer not to embed the URL into my code, by just appending the id to the existing URL

```
(html/defsnippet foo "views/foo.html" [:#main]
  [ctxt]
  [:a@href] (html/append (ctxt :id)))
```

Comment: I haven't found a good way to ahev selectors extend to attributes in enlive but I'd like to.

Answer (score 6):

@ddk answer is spot on but you may prefer a more generic way to solve the problem

```
(defn update-attr [attr f & args]
    (fn [node]
      (apply update-in node [:attrs attr] f args))))
```

and then

```
(update-attr :href str "123")
```

Comment: Why not add this to Enlive? Just needed it.

Comment: I would like this to be included also, there are situations where modifying links is needed and at the moment there is no obvious way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

You could always write your own `append-attr` in the same vein as `set-attr`. Here is my attempt

```
(defn append-attr
  [& kvs]
    (fn [node]
      (let [in-map (apply array-map kvs)
            old-attrs (:attrs node {})
            new-attrs (into {} (for [[k v] old-attrs] 
                                    [k (str v (get in-map k))]))]
        (assoc node :attrs new-attrs))))
```

Which gives the following, when appending `"/bar"` to `href`, on enlive's representation of `<a href="/foo">A link</a>`

```
((append-attr :href "/bar") 
  {:tag :a, :attrs {:href "/foo"}, :content "A link"})
;=> {:tag :a, :attrs {:href "/foo/bar"}, :content "A link"}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. was hoping that there might be something I was just missing. Will mark this as solution if no one else knows anything magical :)