# Update and normalize attr src in enlive

Tags: clojure, enlive

I just start programming recently and I have this problem, so I have this html snippet. I want parse the src attribute of the img and normalize it with urly path normalization, and add some new path to the src.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="content">lorem ipsum
        <img style="margin-top: -5px;" src="/img/car.png" />
    </div>
    <img style="margin-top: -5px;" src="/img/chair.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

become this

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="content">lorem ipsum
        <img style="margin-top: -5px;" src="/path1/img/car.png" />
    </div>
    <img style="margin-top: -5px;" src="/path1/img/chair.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

I think of this method but i just can't find the way to acquire the src value

```
(html/deftemplate template-about "../resources/public/build/about/index.html"
[]
[:img] (html/set-attr :src (str "path1" (urly/path-of ("the src value")))
)
```

Comment: See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/enlive-clj/Bz6TTu02Qv8. I believe it addresses the exact problem you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for an `update-attr` function, was [discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586849/append-to-an-attribute-in-enlive)

As in:

```
(html/deftemplate template-about "../resources/public/build/about/index.html"
[]
[:img] (fn [node]
          (let [href (-> node :attrs :href)]
             (assoc-in node [:attrs :href] (urly/path-of href))))
```

Or taking the generic path

```
(defn update-attr [attr f & args]
    (fn [node]
      (apply update-in node [:attrs attr] f args))))
```

and then

```
(update-attr :href urly/path-of)
```