# Clojure: partly change an attribute value in Enlive

Tags: clojure, enlive

I have this `test.html` file that contains:

```
<div class="clj-test class1 class2 col-sm-4 class3">content</div>
```

A want to define a template that changes only a part of an html attr value:

```
(deftemplate test "public/templates/test.html" []
  [:.clj-test] (enlive/set-attr :class (partly-change-attr #"col*" "col-sm-8")))
```

This would render:

```
...
<div class="clj-test class1 class2 col-sm-8 class3">content</div>
...
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the `update-attr` fn suggested by Christophe Grand [in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586849/append-to-an-attribute-in-enlive):

```
(defn update-attr [attr f & args]
  (fn [node] (apply update-in node [:attrs attr] f args)))
```

Pretty cool! We can use it directly :

```
(enlive/deftemplate test-template "templates/test.html" []
  [:.clj-test] (update-attr :class clojure.string/replace #"col-.*?(?=\s)" "col-sm-8"))
```

Or build from it a more specific fn:

```
(defn replace-attr [attr pattern s]
      (update-attr attr clojure.string/replace pattern s))

(enlive/deftemplate test-template "templates/test.html" []
      [:.clj-test] (replace-attr :class #"col-.*?(?=\s)" "col-sm-8"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this works for you, but if you know the class you are removing exactly you can do this.

```
(enlive/deftemplate test-template "templates/test.html" []
              [:.clj-test] (enlive/remove-class "col-sm-4")
              [:.clj-test] (enlive/add-class "col-sm-8"))
```

In the repl:

```
(apply str (test-template))
=> "<html><body><div class=\"class1 clj-test class2 col-sm-8 class3\">content</div></body></html>"
```

Comment: Pretty cool! I didn't know about `remove-class` or `add-class`. Thanks! The only thing that miss seems to be the way to match any `col-...` class. Still, these are great fns.